# Heyawake - help continue puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is my first try on Heyawake and I am stuck. Can you give a hint for the next move. The cells marked with dots must be white.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

> Check the 3 box

The next step

> The 3 has two possibilities; one of them immediately leads to the white region being disconnected.